# Add all numeric values javascript backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am iterating through a collection and calling an attribute that is a numeric value, instead of just showing each value one by one, how do I add them all up into one total sum?

```
playersCollection.each(function(player) {
    var allPoints = player.get('points');
    alert(allPoints);
});
```

Above returns like

```
 0
 10
 5
 3
```

Instead I want to add those numbers so I get

```
18
```

Comment: @RustyToms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716189/keypress-in-backbone-js cool thanks for taking the effort to doing that.

Comment: @RustyToms did you get the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic `reduce`:

```
var allPoints = playersCollection.reduce(function(sum, player) {
    return sum + player.get('points');
}, 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uqm6J/

Backbone collections have [various Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) mixed in, one of those is [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce). Any time you want to feed the result of a computation back to itself, you want to look at `reduce` and you can think of `a + b + c + d` as `(((0 + a) + b) + c) + d`, the parentheses outline the feedback.

Comment: nice, I came across reduce, but it's nice to see it in my context makes more sense now.

Comment: You can use [`_.chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) and [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter): `c.chain().filter(...).reduce(...).value()`.

Comment: `var allPoints = playersCollection.where({team: 'Ballaz'}).reduce(function(sum, player) {
       return sum + player.get('points');
   }, 0);` I ran this? I will be changing the 'Ballaz' string to a variable though when it's ready.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to keep the allPoints variable outside of the scope of the each() callback function.

```
var allPoints = 0;
playersCollection.each(function(player) {
    allPoints = allPoints + player.get('points');
});
alert(allPoints);
```

That should provide you with a Total

Comment: Oh yeah? I did this but I didnt write `allPoints = allPoints + player.get('points');` that was my problem