# Backbone JS keypress events in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I'm building a small application with backbone js, with a grid that should be navigable using the keyboard. I can't get anything on keypress or keyup events in the views.

Here is the code:

```
// ALL DETAILS VIEW [wrapper]
App.Views.Details = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on( 'add', this.addOne, this );
    },

    events: {
        'keypress': 'keyAction',
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each( this.addOne, this );
        return this;
    },

    addOne: function(detail) {
        var detailView = new App.Views.Detail({ model: detail, collection: this.collection });
        this.$el.append(detailView.render().el);
    },

    keyAction: function(e) {
        console.log('here');
    }
});

// SINGLE DETAIL VIEW
App.Views.Detail = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',

    template: template('detailView'),

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on( 'change', this.render, this );
    },

    edit: function(e) {
        var field = $(e.target).closest('.editable');
        field.addClass('editing');

        field.find('input').focus().select();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    }
});
```

**App.Views.Details** contains one or many **App.Views.Detail**. It should be able to navigate each view using the arrow keys, but no events are seen in **App.Views.Details**.

Maybe this isn't the right way to do this, but I'm new at backbone and I'm open for suggestions.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure that your view is rendered and attached to DOM?

Comment: More info on keypress here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716189/keypress-in-backbone-js

Comment: Yes it is @VahanVardanyan.

Yeah, I check it out before, but I didn't want to do this `$(document).bind('keydown', this.on_keypress);`. I though it can be posible via the `events: { ... }` @bvoleti

Comment: @GigaC actually it's possible, but the entire element should be focused or set the tabindex. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vvahans/khqd7zfo/) is the fiddle that you can play with.

Comment: I think the whole problem is that my elements are <div> and it is not possible to focus on them :/ I got a table generated with divs :/ As I said I am very new in this. thank you anyway :* @VahanVardanyan